# Is the given prolog term a binary tree

Tags: types, prolog, binary-tree, predicate

I have defined whether a given term is a member of a binary tree by the definitions:

```
isBtMember(E,bt(E,_L,_R)).
isBtMember(E,bt(_Rt,L,_R)) :- isBtMember(E,L).
isBtMember(E,bt(_Rt,_L,R)) :- isBtMember(E,R).
```

and by using this, I want to create a definition to check whether the give term is a binary tree or not.

Now when it comes to my definition of `isBtMember`, it works, but not for queries such as:
`?- btMember(bt(a,b),bt(_,_,_)).` in which I try to ask whether a wrong definition of a `bt` could be a member of any `bt`. But let's leave that aside.

Now, my thinking for my definition of `isBt` is something like this:
`isBt(bt(E,L,R)) :- isBtMember(bt(_,_,_),L), isBtMember(bt(_,_,_),R).`
in which I check if the left node and the right node is a binary tree? But seemingly this definition is wrong since it gives wrong results in queries.

Any suggestions on my mistake, or  a better way?
Thanks

EDIT: This is an alternative solution in my mind. It feels not right because `_E` can take any value such as `isBt(bt(asd(a,b,c,), nil,nil))` and still return true.

```
isBt(nil). 
isBt(bt(_E,nil,nil)). 
isBt(bt(_E,L,nil)) :- isBt(L). 
isBt(bt(_E,nil,R)) :- isBt(R). 
isBt(bt(_E,L,R)) :- isBt(L), isBt(R).
```

Comment: I don't see a representation of a null node. As such, your base case `isBtMember(E,bt(E,_L,_R)).` is flawed. It succeeds regardless of what `_L` or `_R` happen to be. Thus, `isBtMember(E, bt(E, +(2,3), foo(a,b,c)))` succeeds (it says that `bt(E, +(2,3), foo(a,b,c))` is a binary tree). In Prolog, a variable can theoretically be bound to any Prolog term whatsoever. If your logic allows that binding to result in success, then that's what you get.

Comment: @lurker I see. And how would the definition could be fixed? How should I correctly define L and R to be binary trees as well?

Comment: You could use your `isBt` but you'll have to get it working. Your definition isn't logical. `bt(E, L, R)` is a binary tree if `L` and `R` are both binary trees or one or both are nil. It doesn't depend on member.

Comment: I formed this definition:  `isBt(nil).
isBt(bt(_E,nil,nil)).
isBt(bt(_E,L,nil)) :- isBt(L).
isBt(bt(_E,nil,R)) :- isBt(R).
isBt(bt(_E,L,R)) :- isBt(L), isBt(R).` do you think it has any logical errors now. Feels fishy @lurker

Comment: You should update your question with the code you intend. Having it in a comment makes it not very visible to most readers and is harder to read. As far as the logic, don't go by how it 'feels'. Read through it. Why do you say it 'feels" fishy? Did you try it and does it work or not? If not, what went wrong?

Comment: all you need is the first and the last line in your latest solution. the three middle lines are completely redundant -- worse, they would generate extra solutions.

Comment: You have 5 rules for `isBt/1`. If you examine them closely, you'll find that the middle 3 are redundant with the first and fifth rule. In other words, for example, with just the first and last rule, `isBt(bt(_E,L,nil)).` will succeed if `L` is a binary tree. That's because you already have a rule that says `nil` is a valid binary tree.

Comment: In your original question, you seem to be implying that `btMember(bt(a,b),bt(_,_,_)).` is succeeding for you but you want it to fail? It succeeds because, by your rules, `bt(bt(a,b), _, _)` is a valid binary tree. And why not? It''s a binary tree where the value of the top node happens to be the term `bt(a, b)`. If you want the node values to be of a specific form, you'll need to incorporate that into your rules.